# Servlet Service poor Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, aem

What is the difference between `ServletService` and `PoorServlet` in general? When to use just a servlet and when to define a servlet as OSGI Service?

`PoorServlet`:

```
public class PoorServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //Do something fun here
    }
}
```

`ServiceServlet`:

```
@Properties({
        @Property(name="service.pid", value="mycompany.ServiceServlet",propertyPrivate=false),
        @Property(name="service.description",value="Service servlet", propertyPrivate=false),
        @Property(name="service.vendor",value="mycompany", propertyPrivate=false)
})
public class ServiceServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //Do something fun here
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PoorServlet` is not an OSGi service and therefore won't be registered in the Sling servlet engine. As a result it won't be available under any path. It is a simple POJO and Sling don't know anything about it.

`ServiceServlet` in your example is not really an OSGi component as well. In order to make it OSGi component, you should use add `@Component` and `@Service` annotations. Then you can add `sling.servlet.paths` property which should contain the servlet path or paths. After these modifications, you can access your servlet under appropriate path.

There is also useful `@SlingServlet` annotation which can be used instead of `@Component`, `@Service` and all servlet-related properties:

```
@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/my/path")
public class ServiceServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
...
```

Please find more information in the [Sling documentation](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html).